# How to unapply the very first migration in django 1.7

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

It looks like rolling back to any migration is possible using:

```
./manage.py migrate <app> <migration_to_go_to>
```

However, this requires an actual migration to be applied, and I need to rollback the very first migration!

Specifically, I want to rollback the built-in "sessions" app (which only has one migration, "0001_initial".)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are right.  Because I thought of the question in different terms ("unapply" instead of "migrate back", "very first" instead of "initial") I didn't see that question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just do:

`./manage.py migrate <app> zero`

Comment: This indeed dropped all tables and migration history, but it did not delete my `0001_initial.py` migration file. Could you please confirm whether I should manually delete it or not?

Comment: It kind of depends on what you are trying to achieve with a backwards migration. You may benefit from a deeper understanding of the migration system before running backwards migrations, as they can get you in a mess if used wrongly!
There are two migration commands. `makemigrations` will look at your models, compare them with any migration files, and create any necessary migration files that you need. It doesn't interact with the database.
On the other hand, `migrate` runs commands on your database based on whatever migration files are there. It won't add/delete migration files.

Comment: It is bonkers that it's `zero` and not `0000`